# Self-signed SSL vs Diffie-Hellman exchange for mobile app?

Tags: android, security, ssl, cryptography

I'm working on protecting communications between an app I'm writing for school, and the server back-end. My initial plans were to set up a Diffie-Hellman exchange between the Android client, and my PHP server. However, I know SSL uses a fairly similar (if, I understand correctly, it may be the same) public key exchange protocol, and appears to have more native support, and better documentation.

Would switching to self-signed SSL, with the certificate hard-coded in my app, be better/worse than setting up a Diffie-Hellman exchange? Would one offer better network/battery/cpu performance?

I know that both methods don't really protect against a Man-in-the-middle attack, but, at this point, my priority is simply protecting against eavesdroppers.

Comment: SSL can use different key exchange protocols, not only DH. Also key exchange is only part of the picture, even if you manage to get it right, there are a whole bunch of other things required for the protocol to be actually secure (key derivation, integrity checks, replay protection, etc.). So see below and just learn how to use SSL.

Answer (score 3):

Use SSL. It's already done, and it isn't vulnerable to MITM if you use it correctly.

Comment: +1, and agreed. Don't roll your own crypto system if you can avoid it, and you should always try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

As previous writer said, DH is vulnerable to MITM attack so stay way from it.

User self-signed SSL. this will provide you data integrity and confidentiality.
SSL is not vulnerable to MITM and performance wise its pretty fast.
Google research on SSL performence... 
https://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html

Import server certificate into your client so that client can do the SSL handshake with server.

Comment: I was going to put a -1, but as this is a first answer I won't. [1] Only basic implementation of DH is vulnerable to MITM. DH implementation with authentication is not. [2] Self-signed SSL certificate is a fake sense of security, and is subject to MITM. Anyone can intercept a certificate exchange and substitute your self-signed cert with another self-signed cert. Sitting in between and encrypting/decrypting traffic, there is no way to understand if you talking to a real server or not. Bad idea. To use it properly the certificates must be signed by a trusted party.

Comment: @oleksii But if you hard-code the self signed certificate in your app, then the self signed certificate becomes a root of trust, and there is no problem.

Comment: @ntoskrnl You might be able to do that, but the problem then becomes with the certificate maintenance: expiration, revocation, scalability. There is also a fundamental flaw: you cannot trust something that nobody else trusts. It's perfectly fine to use self-signed certs for local testing. But not in the production code.